# Lagrange's multipliers exercise

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Can you help me to understand what to do in the following question?

**The question is just to choose one alternative, justifying your answer.**

Which of the following sets of restrictions and points will be able to apply Lagrange's multipliers method to find the 
extrema of a function?

a) $g(x,y)=\sin x^2+y^2 \cos y$ and $\{(\sqrt{\pi},0),(0,\pi/2),(0,0)\}$.

b) $g(x,y)=x-y^2$, with $0\leq y \leq 1$ and $\{(0,0),(1/4,1/2)\}$.

c) $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$ and $\{(1,0),(0,-1)\}$.

d) $g(x,y)=x^2-3x+4y^2-3z^2-6z-3/4$ e $\{(0,\sqrt{3}/4,0),(3/2,0,-1)\}$.

What I am suppossed to do? To see if the points are critical points of $g$ are on the sets mentioned?

Thank you

The question in the original language. 
[image]

Comment: Your question is not very clear. (Is $g$ an objective function or a constraint function? What are the sets of points?). Is this taken verbatim from what you were given?

Comment: smcc, I do not understand your question. I have to choose one alternative explaining why, and it is the form i was given the exercise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It surely cannot be the question as it was given (i.e. verbatim) because "Which of the following sets of restrictions and points will be able to apply Lagrange's multipliers method to find the extrema of a function?" does not make sense grammatically. Also, I asked what $g$ is (even if it was not explicitly stated in the question, perhaps you have been using $g$ to denote the objective function, or perhaps the constraint function). Why not post an image of the question?

Comment: Smccv I have the same problem in understanding it. Maybe is a translation problem. I will write the question in the original language. Portugues